# Program to find primes execution take some time

Tags: c, performance, primes

I wrote a C program to print prime number on a given range for exercising.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void) {
int num1,int num2;
bool flag;
int i,j,count=0;

printf("Enter range 1:");scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("Enter range 2:");scanf("%d",&num2);

if(num1<2)
    num1++;

for(i=num1;i<=num2;i++){
    j=2;
    while(j<i){
        if(i%j==0){
            flag=false;
            break;
        }
        else{
            flag=true;
        }
        j++;
    }
    if(flag){
        printf("%d ",i);
        count++;
    }
}
printf("\n");
printf("Number of prime number between %d and %d is %d\n",
                                            num1,num2,count);
return 0;
}
```

The code works as I expected but when I input the range between 1-100000 or larger  the program print the output like infinite looping  and I have to wait some time for the program print all the prime number.

My question is why the program take some time to print all the prime number between the range of 1-100000 or larger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some minor improvement:

- Skip all even numbers except `2`.
- The condition `j<i` is not necessary, calculating until the square root of `i` is
  enough.

However, it's still not fast for large numbers because the algorithm is slow. Consider an efficient algorithm to find prime numbers, e.g:  [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 2):

The below code will give you better efficiency. There are many unnecessary checks in your code.

```
   for(i=num1;i<=num2;i++)
   {   
      flag = 0;
      for(j=2;j<=(i/2);j++)
      {   
         if(i%j == 0)
         {   
            flag = 1;
            break;
         }   
      }   
      if(!flag)
      {   
         printf("%d ",i);
         count++;
      }   
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> why the program take some time

1. Because all programs take some time (and that time usually depends on efficiency of the algorithms used by the program).
2. You used a very inefficient algorithm to decide whether the number is prime
3. You should study computational complexity (the big-O notation), and see how many operations your program executes (a *lot*).